# Is everything that is known to exist in the world a system?

Tags: reference-request

I was looking at some philosopher's neologisms where he uses new words to essentially describe old concepts from systems theory by generalizing them a bit by replacing the "system" in their defintion with "everything".
Outside our mental conceptions where we can define something as not being a system is there anything in the world that can't be thought as being a system?

Comment: Without serious clarification this question remains incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In system engineering terms a system can be defined as something which carries out some kind of process. An open system receives input, processes it and delivers output. A closed system feeds its output back as its own input. A key underlying principle for this definition is that a system is dynamic, it changes with time.

Anything which does not behave like this is not a system. A ticking clock is a system, a broken clock is not.

Bending the meaning of a "process" is one way to expand the scope of what a system is, but if you bend it far then most of systems theory is no longer relevant and your thesis becomes hard to justify.

Astronomers talk of "the solar system" and, further afield, "star systems" and suchlike. These are indeed systems in the sense that they evolve over time and can be analyzed. But treating say a meteor swarm as a system becomes more of an analogy than a useful understanding, as there are no internal processes going on.

Possibly the most useful expansion has been the distinction between hard and soft systems. The processes in a hard system can be rigidly defined and their behaviour modelled analytically. A vehicle engine is a hard system. The processes in a soft system are inherently unpredictable, typically because people are involved, and soft systems engineering can be as much the art of common sense as actual engineering. A call center is a soft system.

Answer (score 1):

Simply a system is a network  of entities working (in most cases harmony)My observation currently seems to be of entities using the bottom up approach to almost anything. Many sub-systems employ this approach to achieve more.

Therefore;

Yes. Many things that we know are systems. You as an example are a system. You are a system because your body is made up of cells which then make up organs, organs make up your body, your body links up with like minded people to make a society and so forth... to the end we get the human race. The human race can be traced down to an individual cell.

Comment: Question incomprehensible. Answer incomprehensible. Ist there a system behind this?

Comment: Probably. The system of symmetric question-response quality.   Incomprehensible questions attract incomprehensible answers .